# C# How can I edit specific lines of JSON using text boxes

Tags: c#, json, wpf, amazon-s3, key

I'm building a WPF application in Visual Studios 2015 c# and need to be able to edit a config file from the application

In the application I have a TabItem with some text boxes that are populated by a config file request from a S3 Bucket.

The text boxes are populated base on a selection change event from a combobox

The issue here is being able to edit a specific line, every time I try I overwrite the whole config with just the new data instead of editing the current data.

This is the JSON structure I am using.

```
[
  {
    "ClientId": 23,
    "EmailVersionId": "u74hdta58jmf",
    "ClientName": "ClientName",
    "emailTemplateConfigs": [
      {
        "emailTypeName": "EmailName",
        "emailTypeId": 15,
        "subject": "subject",
        "fromAddress": "from address",
        "headerFooterReplacements": [
          {
            "placeholder": "##HEADER_PHONENUMBER##",
            "value": "0000 000 000"
          },
          {
            "placeholder": "##HTML_TITLE##",
            "value": "Title"
          },
          {
            "placeholder": "##EMAIL_HEADING##",
            "value": "Heading"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "emailTypeName": "EmailName",
        "emailTypeId": 29,
        "subject": "subject",
        "fromAddress": "from address",
        "headerFooterReplacements": [
          {
            "placeholder": "##HEADER_PHONENUMBER##",
            "value": "0000 000 000"
          },
          {
            "placeholder": "##HTML_TITLE##",
            "value": "Title"
          },
          {
            "placeholder": "##EMAIL_HEADING##",
            "value": "Heading"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "ClientId": 33,
    "EmailVersionId": "jcna53sj231h",
    "ClientName": "ClientName",
    "emailTemplateConfigs": [
      {
        "emailTypeName": "EmailName",
        "emailTypeId": 12,
        "subject": "subject",
        "fromAddress": "from address",
        "headerFooterReplacements": [
          {
            "placeholder": "##HEADER_PHONENUMBER##",
            "value": "0000 000 000"
          },
          {
            "placeholder": "##HTML_TITLE##",
            "value": "Title"
          },
          {
            "placeholder": "##EMAIL_HEADING##",
            "value": "Heading"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "emailTypeName": "EmailName",
        "emailTypeId": 49,
        "subject": "subject",
        "fromAddress": "from address",
        "headerFooterReplacements": [
          {
            "placeholder": "##HEADER_PHONENUMBER##",
            "value": "0000 000 000"
          },
          {
            "placeholder": "##HTML_TITLE##",
            "value": "Title"
          },
          {
            "placeholder": "##EMAIL_HEADING##",
            "value": "Heading"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

The parts I'm trying to update with the text boxes are

```
    "emailTypeName": "EmailName",
    "emailTypeId": 15,
    "subject": "subject",
    "fromAddress": "from address",
```

But when making the edit it also need to save the info to the correct client and the correct template using the client id and email type id as keys.

```
            GetObjectRequest requestconfig = new GetObjectRequest();
            requestconfig.BucketName = "bucket";
            requestconfig.Key = "key";

            GetObjectResponse response = s3Client.GetObject(requestconfig);

            using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(response.ResponseStream))
            {

                string json = r.ReadToEnd();
                dynamic jsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
                if ((int)emailTempConfig.emailTypeId == templateID)
                {

                    jsonObj["EmailTemplateConfig"][0]["EmailsTypeName"] = EmailNameText.Text;
                    output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonObj, Formatting.Indented);

                }


            }


            PutObjectRequest requestConfig = new PutObjectRequest();
            requestConfig.BucketName = "bucket";
            requestConfig.Key = "key";
            requestConfig.ContentType = "application/json";
            requestConfig.ContentBody = output;

            s3Client.PutObject(requestConfig);
```

This is where I'm at with the code.

Answer (score 0):

After hours of struggling I finally solved it myself here is the code I used for the reference of anyone else who needs it.

In the end it was quite simple I just had to specifically pick out the email Config I wanted then specifically pick out the template in side that config and just update the text values by assigning the value of text boxes.

```
var Emailcon = EmailConfigs.FirstOrDefault(key => key.EmailId == client);
var Emailtemp = EmailConfigs.EmailTemplateConfigs.FirstOrDefault(key => (int)key.EmailTypeId == templateID);

EMAILtemp.EmailTypeName = EmailNameText.Text;
EMAILtemp.Subject = SubjectText.Text;
EMAILtemp.FromAddress = FromAddressText.Text;
Emailtemp.AdminToAddress = AdminToAddressText.Text;
Emailtemp.SmsContentTemplateText = SmsContentText.Text;

output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(EmailComms, Formatting.Indented);
```

DeSerialize -> Pick out specific location -> reSerialize

Quite simple really.